# Changing the background-image from a list of images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have actually a structure like this.

```
<div class="container">
   <ul>
       <li>
         <img>
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

There is always a background image for the main container. What I want to achieve is to change the background image of the container when I hover the mouse on the image in the list. And the background-image should be the one in the list.

and when the mouse is away, the background image should be the original (the one at the beginning).

Is it possible to do it with css only? or javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: with CSS only no you cannot ... with JS/jQuery yes you can ;)

Comment: You can do this with css using the [:nth-child() selector.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Answer (score 1):

It can not be achieved using CSS. It's in the name: Cascading Style Sheets only supports styling in cascading direction, not up.

You can do this using Javascript

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('foo');

myDiv.onmouseenter = function() { 
    // code to change image here
}

myDiv.onmouseleave = function() { 
    // code to reset to old image here
}
```

Comment: Care to explain the downvotes?

Comment: No downvotes. You have no votes.

Comment: @WillHoskings yes, there are downvotes....

Comment: @WillHoskings learning for you then, you need to click on number of votes to see how many upvotes and downvotes you have. In my case click on 0. Its +1 and -1 :)

Comment: @void Will has 71 rep, so can't do this action until 1000 rep points as stated here https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: Oh ok, was getting a bit confused there. I'll check out the points ladder page later just to catch up.

Comment: @JordiCastilla oh missed that!